# Facebook read_stream post issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Can you please explain me how to get info about posts like this :
https://www.facebook.com/828027970565841/posts/900654699969834?_rdr=p

Or like this 
https://www.facebook.com/882291048492401/posts/881757285212444?_rdr=p

Without read_stream i can get other posts with same scheme by graph.api.com/2.2/{post_id}, but not those. 
With read_stream i can get all of the posts. 
I have noticed that i can't  get information about those posts without read_stream permission.
So i don't understand how read_stream can affect this case, also read_steam is restricted for web apps. 
My question is : how i can access  those posts **without read_stream** that disabled for web apps,  or what changes needs to be done in security settings of post creators to make it visible for me at graph api.
 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The read_stream permission was changed to user_posts permission in API V2.3, see

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_new_features

If you want to read user posts like the ones from the examples you need to request the read_stream permission from the user. If your app has been created before API V2.3 all existing granted read_stream permission should still work.

Comment: Even for apps still using an older API version, `read_stream` will be removed on Oct. 6, 2015. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Comment: Thank you. But since apiv2.0 you can't request read_stream from the user. Now only app admins can get this permission without facebook team review. And it's still a big problem that you can't get likes from the example posts (public posts!!) if the post creator don't let your app to do it.

Comment: I mean now you can get info about this post with your own read_stream permission, not read_stream or user_posts from post owner.